# get classes with tablename associated sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, declarative, tablename

I have a file `EE_log_declarative.py` with all the classes declared, generated by `sqlacodegen engine --outfile declarative_model.py`, that looks like the below, which imports as well all the data types as classes, like BigInteger, Boolean, ForeignKey, String,...

```
from sqlalchemy import BigInteger, Boolean, ForeignKey, String

Base = declarative_base()
metadata = Base.metadata

class DataProvider(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'data_provider'
    ...

class DatePattern(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'date_pattern'
    ...
```

My question is: how do i get only the classes that have a table name associated?

To get the class object in one class definition, currently I'm doing, and it works:

```
EE_log_declarative.Base.metadata.bind = engine
DBSession = sessionmaker()
DBSession.bind = engine
session = DBSession()

data_provider_account_object =session.query(EE_log_declarative.DataProvider).all()
date_pattern_object = session.query(EE_log_declarative.DatePattern).all()
```

The idea is to get the class objects dynamically, as many classes as the declarative will have, but only build the class objects that have a table name.

```
for x in dir(EE_log_declarative):
        attributes = getattr(EE_log_declarative, x)
        is_class = isclass(attributes)
        if is_class:
            try:
                object = session.query(EE_log_declarative, x).all()
                all_class.append(object)
            except:
                pass
```

basically, in the latest function I want to append only the class objects that have a table name associated, but it's not really working as x are passed as a string.

Comment: If you want the actual classes, use `getattr(EE_log_declarative, x)`.

Comment: Thank you Jon!

changing `object = session.query(EE_log_declarative, x).all()` by

`object = session.query(attributes).all()` does the job!